# searching for results in a multidimensional array and adding to a variable

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having trouble sorting through a multidimensional array that I am pulling from an XML feed that can be different every time.  I need to find something and place the result in a variable. I am still learning PHP and this unfortunately is a bit over my head.

I'll break down what I have. An example of my array contained in `$valsarray`:

```
Array
( [0] => Array
        (
            [tag] => GIVENNAME
            [type] => complete
            [level] => 8
            [value] => peter
        )
  [1] => Array
        (
            [tag] => FAMILYNAME
            [type] => complete
            [level] => 8
            [value] => rabbit
        )
 [2] => Array
        (
            [tag] => COMPLETENUMBER
            [type] => complete
            [level] => 9
            [value] => 123-345-4567
        )
 [3] => Array
        (
            [tag] => URIID
            [type] => complete
            [level] => 9
            [value] => customerEmail@gmail.com
        )
)
```

Now I understand that I can get the result by using: `$phone = $valsarray[2][value];`

However, my problem is that if no phone number was given, the XML feed will not contain the phone number array so Array 3 would become Array 2.

So my question is how would I go about looping through the arrays to find if `COMPLETENUMBER` exists and then assigning the phone number contained in `value` to a `$phone` variable?

Comment: Can there be more than 1 complete number entry (with a valid phone number)?

Comment: no just one entry, but my problem was the phone number was not required so it would change the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop would do it:

```
foreach($valsarray as $fieldArray)
{
    if ($fieldArray['tag'] === 'COMPLETENUMBER')
    {
        $phone = $fieldArray['value'];
        break;
    }
}
```

---

If you need to do this type of thing repeatedly on the same array, you'd be better off reindexing it than searching each time. You could reindex like this:

```
foreach($valsarray as $key => $fieldArray)
{
    $valsarray[$fieldArray['tag']] = $fieldArray;
    unset($valsarray[$key]);
}
```

After reindexing it, you can do this for any field you want:

```
$phone = $valsarray['COMPLETENUMBER']['value'];
```

Comment: beautiful mk!!! it worked like a charm! i greatly appreciate it and will accept as soon as it allows me :)

Comment: got it! so if I were going to grab email and phone I would do this?

$phone = $valsarray['COMPLETENUMBER']['value'];
$email = $valsarray['URIID']['value'];

Comment: Since phone is not all you're interested in then this loop method would not be the best approach.

Comment: Abra i would be pulling out only about 6 variables and the array only contains about 150 sub-arrays with 4 lines each as shown above. this will only be happening a few times a day on the server, so would it be that taxing or would the loop be ok?

Comment: It depends on where and how.  This is a good answer I just wouldn't do it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
$tags = array_column($valsarray, null, 'tag');

if(isset($tags['COMPLETENUMBER'])) {
    $phone = $tags['COMPLETENUMBER']['value'];
}
```

Or if you only care about `value`:

```
$tags = array_column($valsarray, 'value', 'tag');

if(isset($tags['COMPLETENUMBER'])) {
    $phone = $tags['COMPLETENUMBER'];
}
```

So in short:

- Get an array of the `value` values indexed by `tag`
- If `COMPLETENUMBER` index is set then get the value from `value`

After the `array_column()` you can then get whatever `value` you want:

```
$email = $tags['URIID'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `array_filter` to get only `COMPLETENUMBER` entries, and set `$phone` if one is found.

```
$items = array_filter($valsarray, function($x) { return $x['tag'] == 'COMPLETENUMBER'; });
$phone = $items ? reset($items)['value'] : null;
```

Based on your other comments, if you want to get the values for a subset of tags from the array, you can use `in_array` in the `array_filter` callback. This could be wrapped in the `array_column` suggested in AbraCadaver's answer to get an array of values for any of the tags you're interested in:

```
$tags = ['COMPLETENUMBER', 'URIID'];
$data = array_column(array_filter($valsarray, function($x) use ($tags) {
    return in_array($x['tag'], $tags);
}), 'value', 'tag');
```

The result would be like:

```
array (size=2)
  'COMPLETENUMBER' => string '123-345-4567' (length=12)
  'URIID' => string 'customerEmail@gmail.com' (length=23)
```